# Scrollbar doesn't add to width when I have min-width on div

Tags: html, css

I have a div, it has overflow:auto and I have content that has a set width to it, (6 photos in a row) when there is no scrollbar they are fine, however when the content goes to force overflow to add a scrollbar instead of adding the scrollbar width to the width of the current div it just takes the space from the inline element space, forcing it to cut off the last photo, and have a bunch of extra whitespace where the additional space is left over. I am using min-width on the wrapper of the div with overflow auto. Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really much you can do about this. A couple ideas:

- Use `overflow:scroll` to force the scroll bar to always display. That way there will be no surprises; it will be consistent.
- Compensate for the width of the (possible) scroll bar in your initial CSS. This, unfortunately, will have to be a guess. 30px or so *should* be plenty.

Another thing to consider is reworking your design. Page elements with `overflow:auto/scroll` can sometimes be useful, but I hear they can have usability problems on some touch devices, and well, scroll bars are ugly ;)

Comment: I have always heard that scrollbar takes 20px - but not sure how much valid it is after few years :) according to ugly scroll bars, there are of course jquery plugins that allow you to customize them with images (they create a set of divs instead of a regular scroll bar)

Comment: Supposing scrollbars are the same size in all possible browsers that is.

Comment: Yeah, I may just go the jquery route and make it simulate OSX Lion scrollbars for everyone, (I use lion anyways).

Comment: @DylanCross: Probably a good idea, you can't trust native scroll bars for exact measurements (plus yeah they're ugly). Personally, I'd try to redesign the UI altogether so you don't need this in the first place. Wish I could find reference for the touch screen thing, I'm not usually concerned with that sort of thing so I don't know a ton about it.

Comment: The way I am using scrollbars I think is better than most, I could easily change my design to do without scrollbars, however I find this the best design for what I'm trying to accomplish, but thanks.

Comment: @DylanCross: If you have a link, I'd like to check it out for my own curiosity.

Comment: The part I am working on isn't complete, so it doesn't have everything I'm adding to it, (which makes the scrollbar a better choice in my own opinion):http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/1682/screenshot20120118at837.png